# Generate Street List From Centerline With "From" and "To" Street Name Attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, streets

I'm trying to sort out an efficient way with which to generate a street list within my municipality that includes "from street" and "to street" street name attributes sorted by municipal ward (I've completed this portion of the ask).

Data I have:

[image: Intersection point data.]

[image: Centerline]

I have joined the Ward data to the Centerline successfully. I'm just not sure about my next step.
As per the screenshots, the intersection data has a connecting ID to the Centerline.

How I translate that relationship into correctly being able to pull street names in a "from" and "to" context is where I am foggy. Within the point data, the `INTERSEC_1` field has the cross streets, but I'm not sure if that alone is 100% the solution to procure what I need via a table join or some other measure.